# How to train mahout with java?

Tags: java, data-mining, data-modeling, classification, mahout

i need to create a classifier by feature, i have 15M rows of data like:

```
{
    "app_entertainment" : 1,
    "app_widgets" : 2,
    "arcade" : 8,
    "books_and_reference" : 2,
    "comics" : 0,
    "brain" : 20,
    "business" : 0,
    "cards" : 5,
    "casual" : 1,
    "communication" : 4,
    "education" : 0,
    "finance" : 1,
    "game_wallpaper" : 0,
    "game_widgets" : 0,
    "health_fitness" : 0,
    "libraries_demo" : 0,
    "racing" : 1,
    "lifestyle" : 1,
    "media_video" : 0,
    "medical" : 0,
    "music_and_audio" : 7,
    "news_magazines" : 2,
    "personalization" : 1,
    "photography" : 0,
    "productivity" : 4,
    "shopping" : 1,
    "social" : 1,
    "sports_apps" : 1,
    "sports_games" : 7,
    "tools" : 15,
    "transportation" : 2,
    "travel_and_local" : 8,
    "weather" : 3,
    "app_wallpaper" : 0,
    "entertainment" : 0,
    "health_and_fitness" : 0,
    "libraries_and_demo" : 0,
    "media_and_video" : 0,
    "news_and_magazines" : 0,
    "sports" : 0
}
```

also for every dataset like this i know if its true or false,
the boolean is if the user with this dataset clicked on ad or not.

how can i use mahout to train a classifier and how do i classify after i trained it?

everything that i found on the net is very abstract, not many examples of how to do it via java

Comment: **What have you tried**?

Comment: i tried to figure out how to train it

Comment: What did you try to figure out how to train it? *Where did you get stuck, what was the error?*

Answer (score 0):

There are very few materials for Mahout on the internet. I referred to the Mahout source code and the source code in [Mahout in Action](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA).

You could refer to 20newsgroup source code for classification.

A simple example using NavieBayes classifier. The vector is the dataset.

```
public List<String> classifyCase(Vector vector) {
        TreeMap<Double, String> resultMap = new TreeMap<Double, String>();
        Vector result = classifier.classifyFull(vector);
        for (Vector.Element element: result) {
            int categoryId = element.index();
            double score = element.get();
            resultMap.put(-score, labels.get(categoryId));
        }

        return new ArrayList<String>(resultMap.values());
    }
```

Comment: its the worst example i have ever see, i need a simple code example of how to train and how to classify, this is not good

Comment: Why you think this is the worst case? I think most people would refer to these examples to write Java code as there's few examples online.

Comment: bacause instead of doing some simple example with 4-5 lines of training its showing how to do it from directory with files, i dont need that and its very confusing, i know how to read from file but they stuffed it to the example that makes it unreadable...

Comment: I guess you mean HDFS coding. Mahout uses Hadoop so there are many FileSystem coding. But you can ignore those code, and run Mahout locally. Basically, you could just use Configuration c = new COnfiguration(); FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration); Then you don't need to consider other Hadoop related code